# How to generate compound tokens in lucene 6 based on whitespace?

Tags: java, indexing, lucene, tokenize

I have a lucene entry like so:

"increased heart rate"

When I encounter the text "increased heartrate" I want to match this entry in the index. This means I need to tokenise the input into:

```
{increased, heart, rate}
{increasedheart, rate}
{increased, heartrate}
```

How to do this with lucene 6+?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Here's the way I've done it, open to suggestion:

```
  public class MyAnalyzer extends Analyzer {


  public MyAnalyzer() {
    super();
  }

  @Override
  protected TokenStreamComponents createComponents(String fieldName) {

    final Tokenizer src = new WhitespaceTokenizer();
    TokenStream tok = new LowerCaseFilter(src);
    tok = new HyphenatedWordsFilter(tok);
    tok = getStopFilter(tok);
    ShingleFilter filter = new ShingleFilter(tok, 2);
    filter.setTokenSeparator("");
    tok = filter;

    return new TokenStreamComponents(src, tok) {
      @Override
      protected void setReader(final Reader reader) {
        super.setReader(reader);
      }
    };
  }

}
```

Note the ShingleFilter, and the use of token separator setting method.